# two different dynamic variables in foreach

Tags: php

I have two variables $items and $stuff[0]

I want to loop each variable through an foreach loop like this

```
foreach($items as $i)
// do stuff

foreach($stuff[0] as $i)
// do same stuff as above
```

Is it possible to set de foreach variable dynamic like

```
foreach(($items = isset($items) ? $items : $stuff[0]) as $key) {
```

So i won't have to write the 'do stuff' 2 times...

Answer (score 2):

how about a function?

```
foreach($a as $b) { 
    dosomething($b);
}
foreach($c as $d) {
    dosomething($d);
}
function dosomething($e) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this (if $items and $stuff[0] has same keys; no reason to merge it anyway)

```
$merged = array($items,$stuff[0]);
foreach((array)$merged as $i=>v) {
   // do stuff
   // $v["key-of-items-or-stuff0"]
}
```